# Причина постановки тире в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

"Насчет билета - хорошая идея". Нужно ли здесь тире и если да - то по какому правилу?

Answer (score 2):

***Насчёт билета — хорошая идея.***

Разговорный стиль. Такое **неполное предложение** возможно в диалоге — как ответ на чье-то предложение или рекомендацию.

*— Предлагаю единственный билет на концерт использовать как приз.*
— [Твоё предложение] *Насчёт билета — хорошая идея!*

Здесь пропущено подлежащее (существительное "предложение"), которое легко восстанавливается из контекста, а между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным существительным  в именительном падеже, ставится тире (предложение — идея).
Теоретически можно даже использовать слово *это*  — ещё одна причина для постановки тире.
*Насчёт билета — это хорошая идея.*

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/706-17_tire_mezhdu_podlezhaschim_i_skazuemym.html)
[Неполные предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/722-26_nepolnye_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

***Насчёт билета — хорошая идея.***

Тире ставится, в устной речи делается пауза. **Структура предложения:** дополнение — подлежащее.

Это особый вид предложений, которые называются **эллиптическими.**

В них подразумевается действие, но оно может выражаться целой группой глаголов, например:  ***Все в подвал*** (идите, бегите, прячьтесь).

Эти предложения **отличаются от неполных,** так как они не соотносятся с соответствующими полными предложениями.

У Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

1. Тире ставится при наличии паузы в так называемых эллиптических предложениях (самостоятельно употребляемых предложениях с отсутствующим сказуемым).

При отсутствии паузы тире в эллиптическом предложении не ставится.

**Примеры:**

*Налево от входа – каменное двухэтажное здание. Лепятся друг к другу дома. За ними – огороды. Тихо в комнате просторной, а за окнами – мороз. Везде –  высокие покои, в гостиной – штофные обои.*

Но: *Снова в час ночной тучи над землёй. Посреди небесных тел лик луны туманный. Весёлые лодки в дали голубой.* (Стихотворная речь).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!